# Grid container fit to size of contents

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have been unable to get the colored container boxes to size to the width of contents. They are always as large as the largest box. What am I missing here?

https://jsfiddle.net/76kywv5g/

I even tried dynamically choosing a different CSS class based on the number of items in the container:

```
.sectionContainer_content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) /*repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr))*/;
    gap: 36px;
    margin: 18px;
}

.sectionContainer_content1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr) /*repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr))*/;
    gap: 36px;
    margin: 18px;
}

.sectionContainer_content2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr) /*repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr))*/;
    gap: 36px;
    margin: 18px;
}

.sectionContainer_content3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr) /*repeat(auto-fit, minmax(340px, 1fr))*/;
    gap: 36px;
    margin: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `justify-content: start` on the grid containers? e.g. `#ame_mindmap_drag { justify-content: start }`.

Comment: Yeah.. unfortunately that doesn't seem to do anything, even on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to have section containers to be as large as their contents, setting up their width accordingly should do the trick:

```
.sectionContainer {
    /* ... other properties ... */
    width: fit-content;
}
```